# Convert flash website to html

Tags: flash

I want to convert Flash website into HTML. I have lost swf files coz of which not able to convert it with google and other tools. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: You are saying you dont have swf files , then how are you hosting this , and also are you looking to rip an existing flash site or some thing

Answer (score 1):

There is one pretty new tool that can also handle a bit more advanced flash files (e.g. containing AS2 or AS3): [convert Flash to HTML5, on the fly](http://www.pixelplant.com/)
Feel free to check it out.
I am currently supporting the team in the area of business modeling, etc.
So any feedback is highly appreciated.

[@ideasenabled](http://www.ideasenabled.com)

Comment: This site can’t be reached anymore.